# How to determine if Biztalk 2010 vs BizTalk 2010/R2 is installed

Tags: biztalk

I've looked in the Registry, and database BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.BizTalkDBVersion to try to determine of Biztalk 2010 or BizTalk 2010 R2 is installed on my system.

What's unclear is how R2 would show up there, is it part of the product name itself?

RegEdit:

[image: RegEdit]

SQL Query:

[image: SQL]

List of BizTalks Available to Download from MSDN: 
[image: List of BizTalks on MSDN]

This is the announcement of BizTalk 2010/R2 in Dec 2011: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalk_server_team_blog/2011/12/08/biztalk-server-2010-r2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of BizTalk 2010/R2.  I know they release previews and news with that name, but I believe it officially released as BizTalk 2013

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case; my colleague also found this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalk_server_team_blog/2012/   But it's by inference only, I never saw in clearly stated words that 2012/R2 became 2013.

Comment: So if the site I'm at had actually installed the CTP for 2010/R2, how would I know that?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7915.biztalk-server-versions.aspx

Comment: Sorry about that pasted the URL and hit enter and it posted.  --  Based on the versioning table listed that wasn't the case for them.